# Image not showing but got value on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to show image but i didnt showing on react native
here is view on react

```
 <Button
          onPress={this._pickImage}
          title="Upload Image KTP"
        />
       {this.state.ImageKTP  ? <Image source={{uri: this.state.ImageKTP}}  style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} /> : null }
         <Button
          onPress={this._pickImage2}
          title="Upload Image Selfie"
        />
         {this.state.ImageSelfie ? <Image source={{uri: this.state.ImageSelfie}} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} /> : null }
```

and here is the result
[image]

this is some source code about pick image

```
 _pickImage = async () => {
        await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        const { cancelled, uri } = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [4, 4],
          base64: true
        });
        if (!cancelled) {
          this.setState({ ImageKTP: uri }, () => {
            this.createFormData(uri);
          });
        }
      };
```

and here is createFormData with parameter uri :

```
      createFormData = async (uri) =>  {
        const {ImageKTP} = this.state;
        if(!ImageKTP) return;
        let apiUrl = 'http://192.168.0.20/Api/uploading.php?ImageKTP = ' +ImageKTP;
        let uriParts = uri.split('.');
        let fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('ImageKTP', {
    uri,
    name: `ImageKTP.${fileType}`,
    type: `image/${fileType}`,
  });


  console.log(ImageKTP);

  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      
    },
  };

  return fetch(apiUrl, options);
}
```

Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: The problem is that the image is not showing in the app or is not getting uploaded? Also, does this problem happens on all mobile platforms or is it specific to one platform?

Comment: its not showing on app but this happen on android device. Ios device not problem at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the file path having an issue. Try making file path like

```
file:///data/user/0/com.testing/cache/Camera/b05a1fae-5fd1-4559-9f50-9e44c2d4ba0d.jpg
```

Comment: which one i have to make file path?

Comment: Your file path currently like "file:/data/..." make it like "file:///data/... "

Comment: it is on uri split or something? i'm still not connect about file

Comment: Yes split it and make it like above I said then try

Comment: i think my problem is the value of database is not full. its like this when get upload on postman